# how can i do when i swipe my finger all clickable under my finger became clicked in android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, gestures, android-gesture, android-touch-event

I have six Image View in horizontal when I swipe my finger on them no item press?  I want to these all buttons pressed when I swipe my finger on them and perform their click functionality like piano and guitar. When we swipe finger on screen all piano button pressed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to invoke click for all items when any one of these is swiped. 
You can implement touchlistener on parent (i.e. onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)), listen for ACTION_UP and invoke which ever code you want to execute here.

Comment: Can you explain what happened?